# Why is replacement so slow for long sums?

Tags: replacement

I have an integral of a sum of many terms:

$\int \int S_y^2 a a^\dagger f_1(t_1)f_2(t_2)^* + ...$

For example

```
Integrate[Integrate[(-I)*a*h*Sy^2*Conjugate[f[2, t2]]*f[1, t1] + (I/2)*a*h^3*Sy^2*Conjugate[f[2, t2]]*f[1, t1] - ... ,{t2, 0, t1}], {t1, 0, t}]
```

where the only time dependence is f which is undefined. And my replacement rule is simple:

```
outrules = {Integrate[f_ + g_, it : {x_Symbol, __}] :> 
    Integrate[f, it] + Integrate[g, it], 
   Integrate[c_ f_, it : {x_Symbol, __}] :> 
    c Integrate[f, it] /; FreeQ[c, x]};
```

I want to replace the integral of a sum of terms into a sum of integrals, and pull all constants out of each integral. My rule seems to work for smaller sums but takes forever on longer ones, how can I speed it up?

Comment: Please provide also en example of your expression with integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the code is slow because `Integrate` will try to evaluate the intermediate expressions before they are fully resolved. You may try using [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html), and do the replacement on the `Inactive[Integrate]`, activating them only at the end.

Also, you probably want to do [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) (`//.`) instead of [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`).

```
outrules = {Integrate[f_+g_, it : {x_Symbol, __}] :> Integrate[f, it] + Integrate[g, it], 
   Integrate[c_ f_, it : {x_Symbol, __}] :> c Integrate[f, it] /; FreeQ[c, x]};

expr = Integrate[Integrate[Sum[RandomInteger[{-50, 50}] h^i Conjugate[
       f[RandomInteger[{-3, 3}], t2]]*f[1, t1], {i, 5}], {t2, 0, t1}], {t1, 0, t}];


(expr //. outrules) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 15 seconds *)


exprInactive = Inactivate[Evaluate[expr], Integrate];
outrulesInactive = Inactivate[Evaluate[outrules], Integrate];

((exprInactive //. outrulesInactive) // Activate) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2 seconds *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!